# How do I toggle css elements using simple dom parser?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm trying to scrape product descriptions on a `div` based on its `id`. If the description is too long it shows a "show more". The `div id`'s are **short-description** and **long description**.

My code works great on **short-description** but invisible to the DOM parser for **long-description**. How can I toggle the **show more** and then call the **long-description** ?

```
function my_function($str){
    $url = $str;
    // break apart ugly affiliate URL
    list($chuck, $keep) = explode('=', $url);
    // call simple DOM library 
    require_once 'libs/simple_html_dom.php';
    // clean up unencoded URL
    $keep = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($keep)); 
    // Get HTML from clean URL
    $html = file_get_html($keep);
    //find div element
    foreach($html->find('*/div[id="short-description"]') as $element){
        echo $element;
    }
}
```

Content I'm trying to get.

```
    <div id='short-description'>
        Eos inciderint interpretaris ea. Eam ut legere aperiri qualisque. 
        In propriae perfecto gubergren        vix. Omnesque perpetua id duo, 
        no mel habeo appetere persecuti. Dico phaedrum qui ad, discere euripidis 
        delicatissimi vim cu.....
        <a class='more'>Show More</a>
    </div>
    <div id='long-description' style='display: none;'>
        Eos inciderint interpretaris ea. Eam ut legere aperiri 
        qualisque. In propriae perfecto gubergren    vix. Omnesque 
        perpetua id duo, no mel habeo appetere persecuti. Dico phaedrum 
        qui ad, discere euripidis delicatissimi vim cu.Eos inciderint 
        interpretaris ea. Eam ut legere aperiri qualisque. 

        <a class='less'>Show Less</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: Solved
Code was working the entire time, didn't realize the raw output had the tags attached. It was including

```
style='display: none;
```

so I couldn't see my output result. I added

```
echo strip_tags($element);
```

and then I could see the output.

Comment: show us also some markup

Comment: Ok I feel retarded, markup?

Comment: Ok I edited, this what you meant?

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is. Does the long description content not appear in the DOM you are parsing, or are you outputting HTML to the browser that includes CSS which hides it? To know how to remove that CSS, we'd need to know what it was and how it was being applied.

Comment: ok I added the content elements. I'm trying to get the contents of div id='long-description'. but it's native state has the style='display: none;'.  I need to toggle the a class='less' to a class='more' so the div style elements will "toggle" to style='display: block;'. So I can extract the contents.

Comment: There's no such thing as "toggling" elements in the DOM. The element is there... style controls display, *not* content. A DOM parser will "see" all elements in a document, regardless its style.

Comment: ok so you see what I'm meaning. When I get_html_contents from the URL using div id='short-description' I get the desired result. When I use div id='long-description'  I get "Output result is empty" I'm fairly confident that its when attempting to get_html_contents from the URL, id='long-description' can't be seen because the element state is set by default to style='display: none;'. on the actual page i'm scraping, if you click the "show more" the style='display: none;' changes to style='display: block;'

Comment: You all were right. I'm stupid. I updated the OP. Take a look to see answer.